# Is it possible that a reader witnesses incomplete files on Amazon s3 while they are being uploaded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a writer which pushes big files to S3 and I have a workflow which polls files of a certain pattern on that S3 bucket. Is it possible that my reader witnesses incomplete files, that is, the state of file when the upload is not yet finished.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [downloading from AWS S3 while file is being updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781418/downloading-from-aws-s3-while-file-is-being-updated)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the object will be available to read unless file upload has completed in both cases, single file upload and multi-part upload. If you want to get informed on upload completion and respond to it, you can enable notifications on buckets:

[Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)